# iOS - UIButton image doesn't fit as expected

Tags: ios, swift3, uibutton, uiimage

I have a `UIButton` that has a default image and if a property is set it changes to the property object (an image);

With the default image, everything works properly and the image fits perfectly but when I'm using the image, I don't know why the image doesn't fit.

Here's the code:

```
    var user: User? {
        didSet {
            self.profileImageButton.setImage(self.user?.profileImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal) ?? #imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus_photo").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        }
    }

    lazy var profileImageButton: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "plus_photo").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal), for: .normal)
        button.layer.cornerRadius = 80/2
        button.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        button.layer.masksToBounds = true
        button.clipsToBounds = true
        button.layer.borderWidth = 1
        button.layer.borderColor = .white
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapPhoto), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()
```

I'm expecting something like this
[image: expected]

But I'm getting this instead
[image: output]

Comment: Even if I swap between clipToBounds and maskToBounds it stays the same, but with a default image (a dummy image) it fits properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this line to your `button` configuration

```
button.imageView?.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Comment: solved :D thanks. I was setting the button property instead of its imageView. Thanks for helping